# SVN Export in Eclipse removes labels on tabs

Tags: eclipse, export, tabs, subclipse

I have a very strange effect when using subclipse with eclipse. Whenever I use Team->Export to export a file from the editor the export works fine, but the label of the tab of the file is removed.

Effect can be seen here: http://www.daspferd.de/img/tabs.png

Strangely enough it happens with php-files, css-files, html-files but NOT with javascript-files. So I'm assuming it's some kind of setting that I haven't found yet and not a bug in subclipse.

Anyone know where I can shut down this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug in the editors. If eclipse opens an editor on the exported file, it might not open it as an IFileEditorInput, and the editors therefore do not set the title correctly (that's the job of each individual editor implementation).

This is just a guess, but it would be consistent with some editors behaving ok and some not. It would basically be a missing feature in some of your editors.